# W3 Validation errors

Tags: validation, html

I am validating against html5 and I know that the validator is not 100% but it even shows it should allow this in it's suggestion...

Ouptut:

> **Line 75, Column 92: Bad value home for attribute rel on element a:
>   Keyword home is not registered.**
>
> ```
> …bomb/" rel="home" title="beefbomb.com"><img src="http://localhost/local_folder…
> ```

It then tells me to take a look at the microformats wiki... http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions

Which defines:

> **Keyword:** home
>
> **Effect on a, area:** Hyperlink
>
> **Brief description:** …indicates that the [referenced document] is
>   the homepage of the site in which the current page appears. can be
>   combined with 'alternate' to indicate for example a feed for the site
>   of the current page.
>
> **Link to specification:** [rel-home](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-home)

Why could this be?

Comment: @Mat that is probably not the explanation for why this happens. I think it's more to do with the microformats not being part of the standard yet. +1'd to even out

Comment: @Pekka I thought this also, but the W3 goes on to say... **Syntax of link type valid for <a> and <area>:** _A whitespace-separated list of link types listed as allowed on <a> and <area> in the [HTML specification] (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes) or listed as an allowed on <a> and <area> on the [Microformats wiki] (http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) without duplicate keywords in the list._ This suggests that the items on the microformats wiki should be part of the standards engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microformats aren't part of the official spec. A future ua could come along that decides to treat links with rel="home" on them as links to go to the homescreen of the device for instance, without going against the spec.

The warning is to ask you, "Have you done this for a reason, or by mistake?". If you know what you are doing and why, it's fine. If you decided to make up a new rel attribute for your own reasons, you get told that it's not in spec, but that a system already exists that uses it.

Comment: I am confused as to why it states below it the valid syntax for <a> tags and says items allowed on the microformats on the page which this is. It is also not a warning but an error which prevents validation. I thought this could be the case but the answer W3 actually gives seems to clash by saying it is valid.

Comment: Because it's only proposed, not actually in the spec.

Comment: the others which say they are proposed, e.g, 'canonical','shortcut','pingback' are recognized as valid by W3 as their comment suggests they should. It also says that out of the proposed table _Changes to this registry may not be reflected in validators in real time._ which suggests that the validators should update to match this table (considering the home keyword was proposed in 2005).

Comment: @George - The change over to using the microformats wiki was much more recent, and it's possible that the other values you listed were added to the validator before the change over. IMHO, the choice of using the wiki has left an shambolic mess, and I would put the validation failure down to using a not yet finished spec and just ignore it.

Comment: True, think you are correct and that this is a bug. Looks like things have changed since my understanding of the issue. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I will go ahead and use it anyway because I feel it ought to be valid.

Comment: I agree. The validator has become more and more irrelevant as the internet has become more and more used. Many common practices are invalid (The old Facebook like buttons for instance), so other than the basics I generally ignore it.